# Implement live streaming images with Azure Media Services

Tags: azure, streaming, video-streaming, smoothing, azure-media-services

I'm trying to make a live streaming with Azure but i realy don't know what i should try first.

The idea is to capture several images each second from Kinect camera and transfering into a smooth streaming through azure.

I've read many tutorials, but all of them consists to save the video and to upload to azure. But at this case, I don't know what do here because is in live. Do I have to convert those images into a video? I feed lost.

Thank's for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Images are not a supported input to the azure media encoder. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn535852.aspx